# Ruby Loop failing to break when using gets

Tags: ruby, while-loop

My code should prompt the user to input numbers until they type 'stop', when it returns the total of the numbers entered. I've written this program two ways, both of which fail to break the loop when 'stop' is entered.

My first attempt was with an until loop, although I feel the control flow doesn't work as well. My second uses 'until true' and 'break'.
I'm storing the result of gets in a variable so that I can convert it to an integer, and I've tested removing the variable in case 'stop' was being converted.

```
# 2nd attempt
total = 0

while true
  puts "Give me a number"
  gets_var = gets
  if gets_var == "stop"
    break
  else
    total += gets_var.to_i
  end
end

puts total


# 1st attempt
total = 0
gets_var = 0

until gets_var == "stop"
  puts "Give me a number"
  gets_var = gets
  total += gets_var.to_i
end

puts total
```

I expect inputting 'stop' when prompted to end the loop and return the total. In no case does 'stop' break the loop.

Why is my loop failing to break?

Comment: Your `gets_var` contains a newline at the end. And so it can't be equal to `"stop"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `String#chomp` method which will return the string without the new line separator:

```rb
gets_var.chomp == "stop"
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp

You can check it out manually in `irb`:

```rb
irb(main):011:0> gets_var = gets
test
=> test

irb(main):012:0> pp gets_var
"test\n"
=> test
```

There's a new line (`\n`) character at the end of the string. It appears always when you're using `gets`.

Comment: That's done it, many thanks.

Comment: My IRB shows `#=> "test\n"` right away, there's no need for `pp`